# Текст на уровне середины изображения

Tags: html, css

Есть следующая разметка:

```
<div class="linkLB">
    <img src="style/images/k1.jpg" width="50" height="26" alt="" /> 
    <a href="/">Читать</a> <a href="/">Перейти</a>
</div>
```

Выходит вот что:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как видите, ссылки `Читать` и `Перейти` выравниваются по низу картинки, и получается,  что картинка выше текста.

Как сделать так, чтобы текст был на уровне середины изображения, не меняя размеры самого изображения?

Comment: попробуйте менять `line-height` у линков

Comment: @cyadvert у меня вообще этот параметр не указан. можете привести пример?

Comment: Попробуйте `line-height: 15px;` - Само собой, что 15px надо поменять на что-то подходящее

Comment: @cyadvert это не помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно воспользоваться свойством `vertical-align`.

```
.linkLB img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Оно работает только для `inline` элементов, `a`,  `img` входят в них, если только вы в ручную не поменяли с-во `display`.

Comment: спасибо. все как нужно